# How to get the size of bitmap in kb

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, image-size

I am trying to upload an image in firebase storage and I want that the image should not be bigger than 50 kb I am trying to get the size of the bitmap so that I can know if the bitmap's size is more than 50 kb the 
image would not be shown for the gallery I have tried many codes that were suggested by many people but none of them worked for me. Please help me in solving this problem. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode , int resultCode , @Nullable Intent data )

  {
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode , resultCode , data);
    if(requestCode == ChooseImage && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){

     userProfileImage = data.getData ();

    try {

      Bitmap bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap (getContentResolver ( ) , userProfileImage);       

            if (bitmap.getHeight () * bitmap.getRowBytes () < 50000)
                    profile_photo.setImageBitmap (bitmap);
                    btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick( View v ) {
                            uploaImage ();
                        }
                    });


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
            Toast.makeText (this , e.getMessage () , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just try ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);   
     byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray(); 
     long sizeinkb = imageInByte.length / 1024;//Size in KB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (requestCode == ChooseImage && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            userProfileImage = data.getData();
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), userProfileImage);
                if (bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getRowBytes() < 50000)
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
                    long bitmap_size = imageInByte.length / 1024; 
                    profile_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            uploaImage();
                        }
                    });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

long variable `bitmap_size` will give you image size in KB

Comment: Do not use any third party library for such small task

Comment: Please tell me where should I put this code. Thank you sir, for giving me help

Comment: Thankyou sir for helping me but I think it compresses images

Comment: yes, it compresses the image, by the way, my code working or not?

Comment: Your code works and thank you for giving you time to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get size in KB:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); 
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray(); 
long sizeInKB = imageInByte.length / 1024;    //Size in KB
```

Thank you.